# SKAction go to and stop at a specific frame

Tags: sprite-kit

Flash has gotoAndPlay() and gotoAndStop() methods for movie clips to skip to any frame. I don't see any methods in SKAction class but is there a way or workaround to simulate this for SKAction instances?

EDIT: Additional info on gotoAndPlay and gotoAndStop: gotoAndPlay(n) brings the playhead to the nth frame. If the clip is 30 frames long and you call gotoAndPlay(15) you start playing from the 15th frame and stop at 30. gotoAndStop(n) takes the animation to the nth frame and stops there without playing.

Comment: what do these flash methods do exactly? Not everyone knows flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no action to play from frame x to y. But it's easy to replicate because the animate actions..

```
+ (SKAction *)animateWithTextures:(NSArray *)textures 
                     timePerFrame:(NSTimeInterval)sec
```

.. take an array of textures as input. You either create the array just with the specific frame textures you want to play, or if you already have an array `allFrames` with all textures you can get a new array with the desired frames like so if you wanted to play from frame 15 to end:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(15, allFrames.count - 15);
NSArray* animFrames = [allFrames subarrayWithRange:range];
SKAction anim = [SKAction animateWithTextures:animFrames timePerFrame:0.1];
```

Comment: Good solution, just ran into this. Was trying to figure a way to have a given animation that I was using on multiple sprites start on different frames of a looping animation so they weren't all synched.  Definitely a good category to have for SKSpriteNode.