# Start/Stop a sprite animation from/on a specific frame in Spritekit

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, xcode8

​I have a sprite animation of 30 frames, 6 of these frames are keyframes and the rest are transitions from keyframe to keyframe.

I am trying to figure out how to do the following:

- When button is pressed the sprite starts animating. Animation will run at least once and then it will stop the animation on a randomly chosen keyframe.
- When button is pressed again, animation will start from the last chosen keyframe and will run 1 complete cycle and then stops again on a randomly chosen keyframe.

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445987/skaction-go-to-and-stop-at-a-specific-frame) but that was asked in 2014. Did Swift and Spritekit change enough in 3 years to make it possible?

Edit:
@Alessandro Ornano
I've tried this:

```
var roll1Textures = ["Roll1Motion0", "Roll1Motion1", "Roll1Motion2", "Roll1Motion3", "Roll1Motion4", "Roll1Motion5", "Roll1Motion6", "Roll1Motion7", "Roll1Motion8", "Roll1Motion9", "Roll1Motion10", "Roll1Motion11", "Roll1Motion12", "Roll1Motion13", "Roll1Motion14", "Roll1Motion15", "Roll1Motion16", "Roll1Motion17", "Roll1Motion18", "Roll1Motion19", "Roll1Motion20", "Roll1Motion21", "Roll1Motion22", "Roll1Motion23", "Roll1Motion24", "Roll1Motion25", "Roll1Motion26", "Roll1Motion27", "Roll1Motion28", "Roll1Motion29"]

let roll1Animation = SKAction.animate(with: Array(roll1Textures[0...5]), timePerFrame: 0.06, resize:false, restore:false)
```

But I get an error message: Cannot use instance member 'roll1Textures' within property initialiser; property initialisers run before 'self' is available.

How did I implement your code in a wrong way?

Comment: Nothing has been changed when it comes to this specific problem in SpriteKit as I know.

Comment: I would say just create a customAction to handle the different states

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it could be useful to your game but now in Swift you can also do in one line:

```
let animation = SKAction.animate(with: Array(textures[0...5]), timePerFrame: 0.06, resize:false, restore:false)
```

In other words you can create an array slice composed by your specific range then re-create the array of textures with `Array`

Comment: My question was to long to post as a comment. Please see the "edit" in my question.

Comment: You should make an array of SKTexture, not an array of strings as you did it